# Product image on single product page is not showing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I hope some can help me with an issue I got (never had an issue like this before, so a little lost).
On the single product page om http://www.donsdesign-skilte.dk/produkt/00-rustfri-250x150-mm/ the product image isnt showing, Ive tried to regen img, and reinstall woocommerce but doesnt help, the image are showing in /shop so now am left wondering :-(

Hope some can help

Best regards
Dan

Answer (score 1):

```
  //Can you use this  Additional CSS
.woocommerce-product-gallery.woocommerce-product-gallery--with-images.woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-4.images {
        opacity: 1 !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Parent element of the picture is hidden by setting `opacity: 1`. You need to delete `style` property of this element to show product image.

Replace this line

`<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery woocommerce-product-gallery--with-images woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-4 images" data-columns="4" style="opacity: 0; transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;">`

with

`<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery woocommerce-product-gallery--with-images woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-4 images" data-columns="4">`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is js error ajaxyLiveSearch is not a function. Try to solve this issue, gallery js will work.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something similar was happening to me, and it was a conflict with another lightbox plugin we had installed. I assume this resulted when WooCommerce made their major lightbox changes in 3.0. Disabling the conflicting plugin was the way we were able to confirm it, because then the image showed up like normal.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this css

```
.woocommerce-product-gallery {opacity: 1 !important;}
```

I don't know what is the correct method.